# Iterate java nested list using Java8 Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, nested-lists

I have a Java list of EmployObject like this

```
List<Employee> emp = {emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4 ,...}

Where the Employee class looks like this 

Public Class Employee {
    String EmpId;
    EmpInfo empInfo;
}

public class EmpInfo {
   String salary;
   String address;
   List<Reviews> reviews;
}

public class Reviews {
   int ratings;
   boolean isGood;
}
```

I want to use Java8 streams to iterate a over the list (List emp) and filter EmpId which has more than one rating (List lenghth > 1) and whose rating is good (isGood == true). The new list will look like

List empRating = {empRating1, empRating2, ...}

```
public class EmpRating {
   String empId;
   int ratings;
}
```

I tried different things but not able to find out an optimized solution. Need help with this.

Comment: Share your attempts.

Comment: How is Employee and EmpRating related. Can you  provide more inputs and the code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Just an example:

- selecting employees who have at least one rating `isGood`
- calculating sum of all ratings

```
employeeList.stream()
    .filter(emp -> emp.getEmpInfo().getReviews().size() > 1
                && emp.getEmpInfo().getReviews().stream().anyMatch(Reviews::isGood))
    .map(emp -> new EmpRating(
        emp.getEmpId(), 
        emp.getEmpInfo().getReviews().stream().mapToInt(Reviews::getRatings).sum()
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What is Reviews here ?

Comment: You have `List<Reviews> reviews` in your `EmpInfo` class

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. isGood is boolean field here. If it's a String filed and if I want to compare isGood="good", how should do that?

Comment: Also if I don't want the sum of the ratings, but just only the rating how can I get it

Comment: Yes, isGood is boolean field in `Reviews` class too.  If it's String you can compare it as `"good".equalsIgnoreCase(isGood)`.  As for the ratings, it's up to you to decide how calculate the total rating - it can be sum, it can be max or average of all ratings, it can be any value which goes first, etc. If you think this answer has been helpful, I'd appreciate if you accept it!  You can use this approach and tweak this code as you'd like to make it the best appropriate solution for you.